# Answer key to Peter Smith, "An Introduction to Formal Logic", exercise 13.C.11

Tags: logic

> If A, B are tautologically inconsistent, then so are $\neg A$ and $\neg B$

This statement is from question C11 at http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/answers/Exercises13.pdf, which the answer says is true, but I don't understand why...

I thought that A,B are tautologically inconsitent means they can't be both true, but surely they can be both false, and hence $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ can be both true?

Comment: Um, why do you say "the answer says is true"? The answer key you link to pretty clearly labels C(11) as **false**.

Comment: That's weird... I still see it writes true for C11... I thought the claim was false, that's why I was confused... Why do I see true in the link?

Comment: "11. If A, B are tautologically inconsistent, so are ¬A, ¬B.
True — if A, B are tautologically inconsistent, then there is no valuation which makes A true makes B false, i.e. every valuation which makes ¬B true makes ¬A false; so ¬A, ¬B are tautologically inconsistent." That's what I see on the sheet...

Comment: x @Dxdy: Very strange. It seems that the PDF does contain the horribly mistaken text you quote, but in my PDF reader this text is then _overlaid_ with an opaque image containing the text I quote in my answer instead. So we both agree that "false" is the right answer. Do you see a nonsense answer to C4 too?

Comment: I suspect the answer key was first written by someone other than the author (who wouldn't commit such a silly mistake), and then he had to redact it afterwards? Perhaps he'll come by to clear it up here; he's sometimes active on this site.

Comment: Okay... That's good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer sheet you link to gives a perfectly good explanation of *why* the claim is **false**:

> False --- Suppose $A$ is a contradiction. Then it is inconsistent with any $B$. But the negation of $A$ is a tautology, and can be consistent with not-$B$ for suitable $B$.

You're not telling us what you find hard to understand about this explanation. Perhaps it will help to see a concrete example written out?

Let $A$ be $\mathsf P\land\neg \mathsf P$ and $B$ be $\mathsf Q$, where $\mathsf P$ and $\mathsf Q$ are propositional variables.

Then $A$ and $B$ cannot be true at the same time (because $A$ cannot be true *at all*), but it is easy enough to make $A$ and $B$ *false* at the same time -- namely, $A$ is automatically false always, and we can make $B$ false too simply by choosing "false" as the value of $\mathsf Q$.

Saying that $A$ and $B$ can be false at the same time is the same as saying that $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ can be *true* at the same time -- and so, by definition, $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ are not tautologically inconsistent.